# How exactly does MEGA's download work?

Tags: download, mega

When you download a file from the MEGA service, you are shown a pretty download progress bar within the browser. Once this progress bar reaches 100%, your browser then begins to *download* the file. That is, only once the graphical download is complete, your browser's normal download process is started. What exactly is going on here?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

It uses the [fileSystem API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileSystem), which basically writes the file to a sandboxed section of your local file system:

> AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\File System\

Comment: Ah interesting. So the graphical download creates the file in the directory mentioned in your answer. The start of the browser download is the movement from that directory to your download destination folder. Is that right? What are the benefits to this?

Comment: Yes, exactly... Well, it seems to copy, not move the file. As for the benefits, i'm struggling to see any! "Resumable" downloads is one, but not being able to choose your download folder isn't ideal. I'm also struggling to find out how long the file is stored in your User Data folder, as i downloaded something from mega about 3 days ago and the 250mb file is still there.

Comment: on linux, I found the file here: "$HOME/.config/chromium/Default/File System/001/t/00/00000006" I compared it to the real file downloaded and it is identical; I wonder if I can just safely delete it as it is now useless and ocuppy 160MB?

Comment: MEGA works with Firefox which doesn't implement the filesystem API, so I don't think this is the whole answer.

Comment: File System is just one of the [HTML5 persistent storages](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/offline/quota-research/#toc-desktop) which can be used to allow download resume. But if resuming is not needed it can just store files in memory, decrypt then and download those using the `saveAs()` method (or [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/#supported-browsers)).

Comment: According to this great answer on StackOverflow [Download files like mega.co.nz](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15994861/12039), it depends on the platform and available implementations. On Chrome it's the file system API, but on other platforms blob builder, array buffers and even flash filewriter.

Comment: There is only one reason for this: files on mega are encrypted and they stay encrypted until they are on your harddisk.

Comment: the folder is different now : **AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\ChromeDefaultData\File System**

Comment: For macOS, it is `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/File System/`

Comment: Is there a reason *why* Mega does this?

Comment: @DanielSteiner You could say the same about HTTPS. It would be more precise to say that Mega itself doesn't have the key - the key is stored locally on your computer, so the decryption has to be done locally as well.

Comment: For Brave, it's here on Windows:
%AppData%\..\Local\BraveSoftware\Brave-Browser\User Data\Default\File System\
You will probably have to browse through a lot of numbered folders or search them all for a file with known file size.