# Where did Mega.co.nz store my download?

Tags: download, mac, mega

So, I had ~3GB free on my local disk and I tried to download a 2GB file. It failed because it said I ran out of disk space. My disk still shows that I have about 400MB free. According to this post ([How exactly does MEGA's download work?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/41068/how-exactly-does-megas-download-work)), it stores the file then copies it(?) but, the path in the answer is relevant to PC and I'm on a Mac.

I have searched for both the name and the filetype and I have scoured the Google Chrome folder in Application Support.

Not only can I not find the file but, now I have even less available space!? Do I really need twice the amount of space and, where do I find this mystery file so I can either use it or delete it?

Comment: Try `/Users/USERNAME/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/File System` ([source](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11676584/198836)) or `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chome/Default/Storage/ext/<extension id>/def/File System/` ([source](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/chrome/Pf8UB_nwrpQ/gDkp3f9aYi0J))

Comment: The first one worked! Thank you! I added the extension and sure enough the entire file is there. Not sure why it needs to copy it?

Answer (score 7):

Try:

```
/Users/USERNAME/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/File System
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11676584/198836)

Or:

```
~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Storage/ext/<extension id>/def/File System/
```

[Source](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/chrome/Pf8UB_nwrpQ/gDkp3f9aYi0J)

Answer (score 3):

On Windows
C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\File System\

Comment: Any source for this?

Comment: This is the correct location for Windows. Helped me a ton as Mega didnt automatically save the file I downloaded so I had to hunt for it myself. Note that it just renames the file to 0000000 so you might need to use the expected filesize as an indicator